# jira.home must be an absolute path. on Windows

Tags: jira

1. I create a generic war using the JIRA provided script
2. I deploy that war to a container
3. I go on the server and edit the .properties to say

   jira.home=c:\tmp\jira
4. When I go to localhost:port/jira I get the following...

> jira.home must be an absolute path. See Setting your JIRA Home Directory for instructions on setting jira.home

I look at the instructions but I look to be doing everything right. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart jira after changing the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Setting+your+JIRA+Home+Directory

I believe the path in the properties file has to have the \ escaped as well, so:

```
jira.home=c:\\tmp\\jira
```

Comment: Yup looks like I missed that part